# How can I apply template function to a range result in Helm?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, go-templates

My goal is to convert values in Values.yaml into the following:

```
CUSTOM_VARIABLE: "TEST_ENV_1=devil,TEST_ENV_2=god,TEST_ENV_3=angel"
```

```yaml
### Values.yaml
env:
  TEST_ENV_1: devil
  TEST_ENV_2: god
  TEST_ENV_3: angel
```

The below template almost does this but I'm getting comma at the end: `TEST_ENV_1=devil,TEST_ENV_2=god,TEST_ENV_3=angel,`.

```yaml
### _envVars.tpl
{{ define "envVars" }}

...

- name: CUSTOM_VARIABLE
  value: "
  {{- range $key, $value := .Values.env -}}
  {{- printf "%s=%s," $key $value -}}
  {{- end -}}
  " 

...

{{- end }}
```

Is there a way to apply template function (e.g. `trunc` to remove last symbol) to a range result in my case?

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
{{range $i, $e := $}}
{{if $i}},{{end}}
{{$e}}{{end}}
```

If actually look for the index and if it's zero it's wont to add the `,` at last. here is if is not behave like normal it checks the **index** also.

```
{{- range $i, $e := . -}}
            {{if $i}}, {{end}}prefix_{{$e}}
        {{- end}}
```

above loop will give output like : `prefix_one, prefix_two, prefix_three`

https://play.golang.org/p/KuRh55BHna8

Read more at : https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/XBScetK-guk/m/Bh7ZFz6R3wQJ

Comment: (Does this approach work if you're running `range` over a map?)

Comment: do you mean range over map won't work together without for ?  sorry if missed anything or I am wrong anywhere I am not much good with GO (range over map): https://play.golang.org/p/uPfTONA6TOW

Comment: `range` works fine; but if you're using `range` over a slice, the index is a zero-based number and it's easy to test if it's the first one (and skip the comma), but with `range` over a map the indices are the map keys and it's harder to tell.

Comment: You can iterate over the keys of the map, though; `{{ range $i, $k := keys $ }}{{ $k }}={{ index $ $k }}{{ end }}`.  Then you have a zero-based index `$i`, the map key `$k`, and the corresponding value `index $ $k`.  (Remember that `range` resets the `.` special variable.)

Answer (score 1):

If you write the `range` call into a helper template, Helm has an [`include` extension function](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/named_templates/#the-include-function) that calls a template and captures its output as a string.

```yaml
{{/* Render the map-type template parameter to a key=value,key=value,
     list, ending with a trailing comma. */}}
{{- define "custom.variable.format" -}}
{{- range $key, $value := . -}}
{{ $key }}={{ $value }},
{{- end -}}
{{- end -}}

- name: CUSTOM_VARIABLE
  value: {{ include "custom.variable.format" .Values.env | trimSuffix "," | quote }}
```

(It is probably cleaner to not generate the comma at all, as [@HarshManvar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68772574) proposes.)